# Issues with Id exit Status

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is my very first time posting of many, and I am in desperate need of help. I am attempting to put together a program to run Craps for school, and I am running into the error listed in the title. I have looked around here and messaged my professor, done everything he has asked, and yet still there is no fixing it. Rather than pester him again, could someone please help me figure out what to do next?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int win1=7;
const int win2 =11;
const int crap1=2;
const int crap2=3;
const int crap3=12;

//prototypes for 5 functions are below, you need to code the bodies for these functions down below the main routine
int rollTheDice();
bool flag = false ;
bool winner( int );
bool craps( int );
void rollMore( int, double );
double getWager();
int diceRoll,dice1,dice2,roll,point;
double wager; 

int main()
{

srand(34);  //the final run will have 34, seed of 6 rolls a 7 -automatic winner, seed of 36 rolls 2-loser

cout << fixed << setprecision(2); //set output format

wager = getWager();   // call get wager and get back the amount the player wagered
cout<< "The amount wagered is "<<wager<<endl<<endl; //i added this cout to verify what  wager is returned from getWager()

diceRoll = rollTheDice();  


if( winner(diceRoll) ==true )  
  {
      cout << "\nCongratulations! You have won " << wager << " $ \n";
  }
else if( craps(diceRoll)==true)    //call function craps and test if true is returned
  {
        cout << "\nSorry! You have lost " << wager << " $ \n";//print loser message and amount loss
  }
else     
  {
  rollMore( diceRoll, wager );
  }

return 0;

//Get the user's wager amount with a cin and verify it before returning the value to main
double getWager()
{
        cout << "Please enter your initial bet, in whole dollar amounts. The starting bet is 5.00$. \n" ;
          cin >> wager ;
          while (wager < 5)
          {
            cout << "I am sorry, the number you have entered is an insufficient bet. Please Try Again \n" ;
            cin >> wager;
        }
        return wager;
}

int rollTheDice()          //method is called and returns the roll of two dice, value between2-12
{                          //you need two dice variables and generate a random number between 1-6 for each dice

    dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1; 
    diceRoll = dice1 + dice2;
    roll=diceRoll;
    cout << "You have rolled a " << diceRoll <<" \n";
    return roll;
}


bool winner( int roll ) //returns true if roll is 7 or 11,else return false
{
if (roll==win1 or roll==win2)
 {
    return true;
 }
 else return false;
}



bool craps( int roll ) //returns true if player craps out which is a roll is 2,3,12,
if (roll==crap1 or roll==crap2 or roll==crap3)
    return true ;
else return false ;
}


void rollMore( int point, int diceRoll, double wager, bool flag )   
{
point=diceRoll;
cout << "You did not win or lose! We are now rolling to match the point by rolling " << point << "\n";
while (flag=false)
    {
    diceRoll = rollTheDice();
if (diceRoll==7)
    cout << "\nSorry! You have lost " << wager << " $ \n";
    flag == true ;
if (diceRoll=point)
    cout << "\nCongratulations! You have won " << wager << " $ \n";
    flag==true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the errors this code is generating ? what should be the expected output of the program ? please provide more details about the question in the question description. 
Also closing brace of main() is missing in your program

Comment: "ld exit status" just means that the link failed. The preceding errors will tell you the reason why, you did not show them so nothing further can be said about it. I see at least one obvious reason why the shown code will fail to link. But there may be other, less obvious, reasons, so it's not possible to authoritatively enumerate all actual errors.